# Is there a fully secure way to do speech-to-text?

Tags: privacy, voice-recognition

Is there a secure way to do speech-to-text that ideally uses end-to-end encryption and guarantees my privacy on an android phone? A solution that requires root access is acceptable, as is a solution that requires self-hosting a speech-to-text service (if so please specify).

It would be preferable if this speech-to-text solution was accessible by using the microphone icon on the android keyboard.

Thank you.

Comment: There are some self-hosted solutions, but I'm not sure how reliable they are and what languages they support (I just remember one name: PocketSphinx). But I'm afraid that microphone icon hooks into Google's speech detection in a hardcoded way (not sure, though).

Comment: A "fully secure" speech to text application does not use networking (it would do it locally on the phone)), so "end-to-end encryption" plays no role. Also: Google encrypts your data between your phone and Google's servers, but then Google can (and does) read your data. So "end-to-end encryption" (well, actually depending what the "end" is) does not help.

Answer (score 0):

As Izzy mentioned, PocketSphinx is  the best solution.  However, it is far interior to Google voice typing  in terms of speech recognition, accuracy unless  you are willing to train it on your voice and vocabulary. Anyway here's the link: https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/